# Web scrapping using Golang Colly, How to handle XML path not found?

Tags: xml, go, go-colly

I am using Colly for scrapping an ecommerce website. I will loop over many products.

Here is a snippet of my code getting a sub-title

```
    c.OnXML("/html/body/div[4]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/h1/1234", func(e *colly.XMLElement) {
        fmt.Println(e.Text)
})
```

However, not all products have a sub-title so the above `XML` path does not work for all cases.

When I reach a product which does not have a sub-title my code got crashed and return an error of

`panic: expression must evaluate to a node-set`

Here is my so far code:

```
    c := colly.NewCollector()
c.OnError(func(_ *colly.Response, err error) {
    log.Println("Something went wrong:", err)
})

//Sub Title
c.OnXML("/html/body/div[4]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/h1/1234", func(e *colly.XMLElement) {
    fmt.Println(e.Text)
})

c.OnRequest(func(r *colly.Request) {
    fmt.Println("Visiting", r.URL)
})

c.Visit("https://www.lazada.vn/-i1701980654-s7563711492.html")
```

Here is what I want

```
c.OnXML("/html/b.....v/h1/1234", func(e *colly.XMLElement) {
    if no error {

        fmt.Println("NO ERROR)

    } else {

        fmt.Println("GOT ERROR")

    }
    
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I figured out what went wrong in your code. Let me start with the final. As you can see, the error is originated from the `panic` statement at line **473** of the `parse.go` file. The package `xpath` has a method called `parseNodeTest` that does the following check:

```golang
func (p *parser) parseNodeTest(n node, axeTyp string) (opnd node) {
    switch p.r.typ {
    case itemName:
        if p.r.canBeFunc && isNodeType(p.r) {
            var prop string
            switch p.r.name {
            case "comment", "text", "processing-instruction", "node":
                prop = p.r.name
            }
            var name string
            p.next()
            p.skipItem(itemLParens)
            if prop == "processing-instruction" && p.r.typ != itemRParens {
                checkItem(p.r, itemString)
                name = p.r.strval
                p.next()
            }
            p.skipItem(itemRParens)
            opnd = newAxisNode(axeTyp, name, "", prop, n)
        } else {
            prefix := p.r.prefix
            name := p.r.name
            p.next()
            if p.r.name == "*" {
                name = ""
            }
            opnd = newAxisNode(axeTyp, name, prefix, "", n)
        }
    case itemStar:
        opnd = newAxisNode(axeTyp, "", "", "", n)
        p.next()
    default:
        panic("expression must evaluate to a node-set")
    }
    return opnd
}
```

The value of `p.r.typ` is `itemNumber` (`28`). This leads the switch to enter into the default branch and gives the error. The methods invoked before the above-mentioned one (you can see them in the call stack of your IDE) set the `typ` for the literal `1234` to this value and this caused an invalid XPath query. To make it works, you've to get rid of the `1234` and put some valid value.
Let me know if this solves your issue, thanks!

Comment: yeah I intentionally add `1234` to recreate a case where the current XPath does not exists. I want to avoid the case where the source got crashed when the Xpath does not exists

Comment: okay, you can add an XPath query for a not-existent node. However, the query must be valid. `1234` cannot be parsed as a valid XPath query. You can change it to something like `test` and check for the returned result (in this case anything as `test` is not an HTML tag).

Comment: Hi @Chau Loi, did you manage it?

Comment: Yes, it works when I changed into `abcd`, it seems that `1234` is not a valid XML path